# Why am I not able to create unit test in my Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution, and I need to unit test some of the methods in a controller.

In all of the articles and videos I see, the solution in the solution in the solution explorer, is just right-clicked and then `Add > New Project >`

Then in the tutorials (such as this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYrXogLj7vg at 17:40), the following windows pops up, and the "unit test project" option shows up:

[image]

Then this option is clicked, and a unit test class is created, ready to go.

But, in my newer version of VS, when I try to click "new project", I get this view, with some other options:

[image]

Now, there are a few things here that don't make sense, first of all my project is ASP.NET MVC, such it doesn't make sense to me to make tests that are .NET Core.

Also, why am I not able to just make a test class "easily" like in all the older examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what you expect,

Select **ProjectType: Test**

and "All Platforms"

Then you can see "Unit Test Project (.Net Framework)".

Comment: thanks! would you by the way know why the test files are f# files, when i try to create mstest modules?

Comment: May be defaulting to F#. Select the language you want from language dropdown.